# How to set default app?

Tags: app

How to set the default app? I.e., after login, user should be redirected to default app, irrespective of what app was being used before prior logout. I tried setting the default app as custom app on my System Administrator profile but this did not work:

[image]

This above setting is for [when users log in for the first time only](http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_profiles_assigning_apps.htm). How to make it the default app for all logins made by that profile? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible without using some ugly workaround using something like Javascript. If you only want them to use that App, then why make other apps available to the profile ?. The best thing in that case would be to make only that one app visible to that profile, other than that, just train users.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change the default App for users (profiles) by:

setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> choose the profile with which you want to change the default App -> Assigned Apps

[image]

Comment: The poster of the question states that they have tried this and it only applies to the first login.  They are looking for a solution that works for all subsequent logins as well, regardless of the app they were using at last log out.